# Rotating $S=1/2$ spinor from $|+x\rangle$ to $|+y\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, spinors

This is a simple question on rotating S=1/2 spinors that I can't seem to get. The general rotation matrix for a spinor by an angle $\theta$ about the $\hat{n}$ axis is given by
$$
R(\theta,\hat{n}) = I\cos(\theta/2)- i\sin(\theta/2)\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \mathbf{n}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is the vector of Pauli matrices. I was trying to rotate a $|+x\rangle$ to a $|+y\rangle$, which should be achieved by $R(\pi/2, \hat{z})$, i.e. a $\pi/2$ rotation about the z-axis. This should be pretty straightforward, but I'm not getting the results I want. Working in the z-basis,
$$
R(\pi/2, \hat{z})|+x\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1-i & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1+i \end{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1-i \\ 1+i\end{pmatrix} \neq \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\i\end{pmatrix} = |+y\rangle.
$$
This prescription works for other rotations however, for eg. a $\pi/2$ rotation of $|+z\rangle$ about the y-axis does give $|+x\rangle$:
$$
R(\pi/2, \hat{y})|+z\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ 
 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = |+x\rangle.
$$
Does anyone know where I might have gone wrong in the first example? It seems really simple but I couldn't figure it out. I was thinking it might have something to do with $SU(2)$ rotations being a double cover of $SO(3)$ rotations, eg. we need a $4\pi$ rotation to recover identity in spinor space, so maybe that introduces some complications in the rotation angles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually quite close to the solution.

$$R(\pi/2,\hat{z})|+x\rangle=...
=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1-i\\1+i\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\i\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}|+y\rangle
=e^{-i\pi/4}|+y\rangle$$

So $R(\pi/2,\hat{z})|+x\rangle$ is, when you ignore the unessential phase factor,
equal to $|+y\rangle$.

---

The picked up phase factors in these relations depend on the arbitrary
phase conventions used to define $|+x\rangle$, $|-x\rangle$,
$|+y\rangle$ $|-y\rangle$, $|+z\rangle$ and $|-z\rangle$.

For example: You could have defined $|+y\rangle=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}-i\\1\end{pmatrix}$
instead of $|+y\rangle=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\i\end{pmatrix}$,
or $|+z\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$
instead of $|+z\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$.
And then you get the same relations, but with other phase factors.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I think you're missing a factor of $1/\sqrt2$ after the third equality. But either way this makes sense. Is there a simple reason why in this case we pick up a phase, but in the second example of rotating $|+z\rangle$ to $|+x\rangle$ we don't?

Comment: @antimornings yes thanks, I forgot a $1/\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @antimornings See my amendment where the phase factors come from

Comment: Thanks for the answer!